# problema em mandar dados do formulário php para o banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

Olá, sou iniciante em PDO e em meu desenvolvimento de um formulário não consigo mandar nada para o banco de dados e não consigo identificar o problema no meu formulário php, alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

ARQUIVO index.php(ex):

```
    <?php session_start();?>
```

```
<input type="text" name="nome" data-required="true" placeholder="Nome*">

<input type="email" name="email" data-required="true" placeholder="Endereço de e-mail*">

<input type="text" name="assunto" data-required="true" placeholder="Assunto*">

<textarea name="message" data-required="true" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>

<button type="submit" name="SendCadCont">Enviar</button>
```

ARQUIVO send_mail.php(ex):

```
<?php 
session_start();
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste", "root", "root"); 

// Verificação do botão quando apertado.
$SendCadCont = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendCadCont', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($SendCadCont) {

    //Recebe os dados do formulário.
    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $assunto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'assunto', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //Insere os dados no DB
    $result_msg_cont = "INSERT INTO msg (nome, email, assunto, message) VALUES (':nome', ':email', ':assunto', ':message')";

    $insert_msg_cont = $conn->prepare($result_msg_cont);
    $insert_msg_cont->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
    $insert_msg_cont->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $insert_msg_cont->bindParam(':assunto', $assunto);
    $insert_msg_cont->bindParam(':message', $message);

    if ($insert_msg_cont->execute()) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Enviado';
        header("location: email");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Não enviado';
        header("location: email");
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Problema';
    header("location: email");
}
```

?>

... E mesmo Assim não envia os dados para o banco de dados. agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Mude esta linha:

```
<button type="submit" name="SendCadCont">Enviar</button>
```

para:

```
<button type="submit" name="SendCadCont" value="1">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Não acredito que era a falta do (value="1").. meu amigo muito obrigado. funcionou 100%

Answer (score 0):

Olá ***M4RC0SJS***, tudo bem?
Altere o seu index.php, para:

```html
<form method="POST" action="send_mail.php">
  <input type="text" name="nome" data-required="true" placeholder="Nome*">
  <input type="email" name="email" data-required="true"       placeholder="Endereço de e-mail*">
  <input type="text" name="assunto" data-required="true" placeholder="Assunto*">
  <textarea name="message" data-required="true" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="SendCadCont">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Existem várias formas de inserir dados numa base de dados em PHP, irei fazer o script da forma que prefiro e que para mim penso que seja a mais básica mas que funciona!

```html
<?php
// Conexão com a base de dados, podes fazer a partir de outro ficheiro e carregá-lo com "include_once("arquivo.php")"
define("HOST",  "localhost");
define("DBUSER", "root");
define("DBPASS", "dbpass");
define("DBNAME", "dbname");

$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME) or die("Erro ao conectar com a base de dados.");

if(isset(SendCadCont)) {
  // Recebe os dados do formulário e armazena-os em vars
  $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $assunto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['assunto']);
  $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
  
  // Insere os dados na db:
  $query="INSERT INTO msg(nome, email, assunto, message) VALUES('$nome', '$email', '$assunto', '$message');
  mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}


?>
```

Espero ter ajudado em alguma coisa ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado, seu conceito utiliza o mysql_connect sendo que na conexão eu estava usando o PDO para ter mais segurança contra ataques SQL(Mas funcionou sim) Muito obrigado.